# Api connector guidelines(not creating a API)

Tags: json, api, rest, laravel

I started using Laravel around a year ago and I am currently making an application where I have to transfter data between multiple REST JSON API's.

I can find a lot of articles how to create API's. However I can't really find any information how to practicly connect to API's and using them in an object orientated way inside Laravel.

I'm thinking about using a model approach combined with interfaces to keep track of API version changes. I want to use repositories to make the API call. Inside this repositories i will use restable method names(e.g. GET,PATCH,POST,DELETE).

I am not sure this is a best practice and I understand this is a question where people can have a lot of opinions about.

If someone can give me some basic guidelines or starting points it would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: I honestly don't have enough experience on this topic to write a quality answer, but [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) is a nice tool for making requests to REST API's

Comment: not really a lot of info in the market. but thanks. it gave me a start!